# SQL Cross-Tabulation, Pivot

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, pivot

I'm working for a company that needs an improved shift management overview. They're used to an excel sheet, and I'm meant to implement a solution on a web browser instead. The format of the sheet is something like this:

```
                 Employee1    Employee2    Employee3
DD/MM/YYY1 Mon   Shift1       Shift2       Shift3
DD/MM/YYY2 Tue   Shift2       Shift3       Shift1
DD/MM/YYY3 Wed   Shift3       Shift1       Shift2
DD/MM/YYY4 Thu   Shift1       Shift2       Shift3
DD/MM/YYY5 Fri   Shift2       Shift3       Shift1
```

My problem is that right now, it appears like this:

```
Date           Shift_Type_Name   Employee_Name
DD/MM/YYY1 Mon Shift1            Employee1
DD/MM/YYY1 Mon Shift2            Employee2
DD/MM/YYY1 Mon Shift3            Employee3
```

I'm using **ASP.net 4.6.1**, and **Microsoft SQL Server**.

I'll attach a photo of the database design for those interested.

[Microsoft SQL Database Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Ajr.png)

Should I **focus on the SQL query** to dynamically add a column for each employee, or should I **use ListView templates** to display it in this design, etc?

Thanks for your interest and help. I've benefited a lot from this community. :)

**Edit:**
The closest I've gotten to a solution for my problem (and perhaps this will help you understand my question a little better) is this pseudocode:

```
SELECT
[Date].[date] AS 'Date',
FOR EACH( SELECT [Employee].* AS THIS ){
    SELECT [Shift_Type].[name] AS [THIS].[Name] + ' Morning',
        WHERE [Shifts].[Type] = @morning_hours AND [Shifts].[Employee_fk] = [THIS].[ID]
    SELECT [Shift_Type].[name] AS [THIS].[Name] + ' Evening',
        WHERE [Shifts].[Type] = @evening_hours AND [Shifts].[Employee_fk] = [THIS].[ID]
    }
FROM [Groups]
JOIN [Employee]
    ON [Groups].[id] = [Employee].[group_fk]
JOIN [Shifts]
    ON [Employee].[id] = [Shifts].[employee_fk]
JOIN [Shift_Types]
    ON [Shift_Types].[id] = [Shifts].[type_fk]
RIGHT JOIN [Date]
    ON [Date].[id] = [Shifts].[date_fk]
JOIN [Public_Holidays]
    ON [Public_Holidays].[date_fk] = [Date].[id]
```

I understand that FOR EACH is not an option in SQL server, but hopefully this describes what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: When you say *What is the most efficient way of parsing the data* are you asking how you should import the source data?

Comment: @destination-data Actually, if you have a suggestion on an improved SQL query, then I would love to hear it!

That wasn't what I meant though.
I'm led to believe I just need to improve my query, and then I could display it in a GridView, automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done some extra research, I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZGjHYS9lzI) to be very helpful in explaining pivoting.

Here's the query I made with its help:

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @SQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @ColumnNames += QUOTENAME(Employee.name) + ','
FROM Employee;

SET @ColumnNames =LEFT(@ColumnNames, LEN(@ColumnNames) - 1);


SET @SQuery =
'
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT
    Employee.name as Name,
    Date.date as ''Date'',
    Shift_Types.name as ''Shift''
FROM [Groups]
    JOIN [Employee]
        ON [Groups].[id] = [Employee].[group_fk]
    JOIN [Shifts]
        ON [Employee].[id] = [Shifts].[employee_fk]
    JOIN [Shift_Types]
        ON [Shift_Types].[id] = [Shifts].[type_fk]
    RIGHT JOIN [Date]
        ON [Date].[id] = [Shifts].[date_fk]
    JOIN [Public_Holidays]
        ON [Public_Holidays].[date_fk] = [Date].[id]) as BaseData
PIVOT(
    MIN(BaseData.[Shift])
    FOR BaseData.[Name]
    IN (' + @ColumnNames + ')
) as PivotTable'

EXEC(@SQuery);
```

I hope this helps someone. :)